# PHP Mysql Table information

Tags: php, mysql, show

This works:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `someDatabase` ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row[0].'<br>';
}
```

And I get the database tables just fine.
Is it possible to grab more information, from that same query?
I want to display the number of records next to each table name, and perhaps more, if more options are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,

run a query like so:

`SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM your-database`

Will give you a bunch of data (rows, collation, etc;)

**EDIT**

You can also run others like:

```
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE `Db`='your-database';
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE `Db`='your-database';
SHOW TRIGGERS FROM `your-database`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look even at the information_schema

```
select *
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'your_db'
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not from the same query. You'd have to get the table names, then run individual "select count(*) from $table". MyISAM does have a row count stored somewhere, which could be retrievable from a single overall query. But InnoDB doesn't store a global count - it would always be wrong if there's uncommitted transactions, and the count would be relative to the user who's doing the count.

Comment: I dunno.. `show table status from db` works for me... my database is MyISAM tho, so you might be right about InnoDB

Comment: Gives me a row count for InnoDB tables also, and it is the correct count.

Comment: Try it again with some outstanding transactions that have deleted/added rows, using a different connection/account.

Comment: Yeah, I know how InnoDB locking and transactions work.  I am just pointing out that at the very least it will give you a decent answer, though not necessarily 100% accurate.